# I am getting errors when compliling an Angular project with `ng build --prod`

Tags: angular

Here are the errors I am getting:

```
ERROR in src\app\admin\product-form\product-form.component.html(8,43): : Property 'title' does not exist on type '{}'.
src\app\admin\product-form\product-form.component.html(17,74): : Property 'price' does not exist on type '{}'.
src\app\admin\product-form\product-form.component.html(26,76): : Property 'category' does not exist on type '{}'.
src\app\admin\product-form\product-form.component.html(41,73): : Property 'imageUrl' does not exist on type '{}'.
src\app\admin\product-form\product-form.component.html(8,43): : Property 'title' does not exist on type '{}'.
src\app\admin\product-form\product-form.component.html(17,74): : Property 'price' does not exist on type '{}'.
src\app\admin\product-form\product-form.component.html(26,76): : Property 'category' does not exist on type '{}'.
src\app\admin\product-form\product-form.component.html(41,73): : Property 'imageUrl' does not exist on type '{}'.
src\app\shipping-form\shipping-form.component.html(5,42): : Property 'name' does not exist on type '{}'.
src\app\shipping-form\shipping-form.component.html(12,44): : Property 'email' does not exist on type '{}'.
src\app\shipping-form\shipping-form.component.html(19,56): : Property 'phonenumber' does not exist on type '{}'.
src\app\shipping-form\shipping-form.component.html(26,58): : Property 'addressLine1' does not exist on type '{}'.
src\app\shipping-form\shipping-form.component.html(33,58): : Property 'addressLine2' does not exist on type '{}'.
src\app\shipping-form\shipping-form.component.html(40,42): : Property 'city' does not exist on type '{}'.
src\app\shipping-form\shipping-form.component.html(5,42): : Property 'name' does not exist on type '{}'.
src\app\shipping-form\shipping-form.component.html(12,44): : Property 'email' does not exist on type '{}'.
src\app\shipping-form\shipping-form.component.html(19,56): : Property 'phonenumber' does not exist on type '{}'.
src\app\shipping-form\shipping-form.component.html(26,58): : Property 'addressLine1' does not exist on type '{}'.
src\app\shipping-form\shipping-form.component.html(33,58): : Property 'addressLine2' does not exist on type '{}'.
src\app\shipping-form\shipping-form.component.html(40,42): : Property 'city' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

Comment: Hi Sanju! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider creating a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can troubleshoot the problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use *ngIf in the Template File or Ternary operator can also be used.

**Template**

```
<div *ngIf="user">
   <span>Hello {{user.fname}}</span>
</div>

<div>
   <span>Hello {{user?.fname}}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution1 : 
Create Interface and assign the interface as object type in component class

```
interface myObjInterface {
   title : string;
   price : string;
   category : string;
   imageUrl : string;
   title : string;
   price : string;
   category : string;
   imageUrl : string;
   name : string;
   email : string;
   phonenumber : string;
   addressLine1 : string;
   addressLine2 : string;
   city : string;
   name : string;
   email : string;
   phonenumber : string; 
   addressLine1 : string;
   addressLine2 : string;
   city : string;
}
```

in Component class :

```
yourObject  : myObjInterface;
```

Solution 2 : 
use ***ngIf** and hide the parent div when object is empty

```
<div *ngIf="yourObject && yourObject.title">
      /* Your html code should be here*/
   </div>
```

Solution 3 :
    in Component class :

```
yourObject  : any = {
   title : "",
   price : "",
   category : "",
   imageUrl : "",
   title : "",
   price : "",
   category : "",
   imageUrl : "",
   name : "",
   email : "",
   phonenumber : "",
   addressLine1 : "",
   addressLine2 : "",
   city : "",
   name : "",
   email : "",
   phonenumber : "",
   addressLine1 : "",
   addressLine2 : "",
   city : ""
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this and the problem goes away,

in product-form.component.ts:

`product = {};` => `product: any = {};`

in shipping-form.component.ts

`shipping = {};` => `shipping: any = {};`

Answer (score 0):

If you write `<span >{{user.name}}</span>`, the compiler verifies the following:

- user is a property on the component class.
- user is an object with an name property.

Importantly, it doesn't check embedded views, such as `*ngIf`, `*ngFor`, other `<ng-template>` embedded view.
It doesn't figure out the types of #refs, the results of pipes, the type of $event in event bindings, and so on.

That being said, you do one of the following solutions:

- use strongly typed classes/interfaces/types
- wrapp your binding under `*ngIf`
- declare your variable as `any`

I recommend going with the 2 first options, define your type because that's the right thing to do, use *ngIf to render the view only when data is available.
In case you don't use `*ngIf`, make sure to use the null-coalescing operator '?' like follows `<span >{{user?.name}}</span>` to null reference exceptions in your template.